# Passing select multiple on a form

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig

I'm using codeiniter ,with Twig as template engine,and I have this select multiple on the template

```
<form action="{{ base_url }}mydirection/encuestas/perfil_interna" method="post" >
     <select multiple="multiple" name="profile_questions">
           {% for question in questions %}
                  <option id="qid_{{question.id}}">{{ question.text}}</option>
           {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
```

this is the function on the controller

```
public function set_profile_internal_question(){
        var_dump($_REQUEST);
}
```

But I get and empty array

and the route only work without the method

```
$route['mydirection/encuestas/perfil_interna']= 'Backend/Questions/set_profile_internal_question';
```

this way doesn't work

```
$route['mydirection/encuestas/perfil_interna']['POST']= 'Backend/Questions/set_profile_internal_question';
```

But its a form,post should work.

Comment: What version of Codeigniter is this? When you submit the form, what does your developer's console log report that's being passed in the POST params?

Comment: the form params of the request are the selected options, but the response code is 302

Comment: your form action points to `mydirection/encuestas/perfil_interna` (assuming route-controller-method). But your function (method) is not `perfil_interna` but `set_profile_internal_question`. Basically the form action should be the method within the controller that's going to do the processing. Try pointing the form to the actual method and then replace `var_dump($_REQUEST);` for `print_r($_POST, TRUE);` and let us know what you see